# Python--writing to file adds null characters

Tags: python-2.7

When I write to a file, using python `open(filename, 'w+')`, I get multiple lines of `NULL` written to the file in addition to the new text.  Python 2.7.3

```
from sys import argv

script, filename, random = argv

my_file = open(filename, 'w+')
added_line = raw_input("Type what you want to add: ")

my_file.write(added_line)

print my_file.read()

my_file.close()
```

I am teaching myself and practicing opening and writing to files (obviously, I guess). I can get the program to run and prompt me for the new text. I also tried  `open(filename, 'a')`.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Works for me; what OS are you running on? And how are you determining that these NULL bytes are present? (BTW, calling `.read()` right after you write isn't going to do anything useful since the read pointer is at the end of the file, but that won't add any bytes, NULL or otherwise, to it.)

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Pro. I am running everything from Powershell and Notepad++. When I write the text I want to add, the Powershell terminal outputs some gibbersish, skips maybe twenty lines and then outputs more gibberish. When I then access the file in Notepad++, it shows maybe 200 lines of `NULL NULL NULL...`.

Comment: Can you try this outside of powershell? I can't reproduce this, and that definitely shouldn't be happening. Have you tried just using mode `'w'`? (`'w+'` truncates the file anyway).

Comment: I ran the script from the command prompt with the same result. Then I changed the script as you suggested to use mode 'w' and commented out the .read() and it works. It also works from the Powershell terminal. Thank you, kindly. Please make an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried opening the file with the `w` option and as far as I know, if you open the file with `w` option you are only able to write to file, so you cannot run the `read()` method. Indeed, `w+` enables you to read and write. (Note that 'w+' truncates the file). `r+` opens the file for both reading and writing.

`my_file.seek(0)` return to the top of the file before reading, otherwise you'll just read an empty string.

Worked for me.